# What is the ruby idiomatic way to set a hash entry to a array before appending to it?

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to create a hash that has a key and an array of values associated with the key.
So I was doing something like this

```
 hash = Hash.new
```

and then later when I have a key I would do this

```
 hash[key] << new_thing
```

but this fails if hash[key] is nil ,  so I added this statement before trying to append the new_thing to the array.

```
 hash[key] = Array.new unless hash[key] 
 hash[key] << new_thing
```

I thought I could eliminate the added statement by changing the definition of hash to

```
hash = Hash.new Array.new
```

but this does not work because each entry shares the same array,  what I really need is this

```
hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Array.new }
```

I know I am probably splitting hairs but, I am just curious, what would be the "ruby" way to do this?

**EDIT:**
Ultimately what I ended up doing is using group_by.  I realize it was not obvious from my question that I was trying to use this structure to group objects with the same property together in a hash.  I am including this to encourage others that may find themselves using a similar structure for a similar purpose to check out [group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

```
["A", 1, "b", 3].group_by { |i| i.class }
=> {String=>["A", "b"], Fixnum=>[1, 3]}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your last `default_proc` version?

Comment: It works, but I guess I was thinking it might be more confusing than the added statement.  I figured this must come up quite a bit and there were some preferred way to do this

Comment: What is `hash{key]`? It is not even valid Ruby code.

Comment: @sawa: A simple typo?

Comment: @sawa: Given the usual location of `{` and `[` on a keyboard it seems pretty obvious that it was a typo. Perhaps if you asked if `hash{key]` was a typo you'd get friendlier responses.

Comment: @muistooshort You may or may not be right about it, but I ask neutrally without making any guess to make it easy for me. Whether or not it is a typo, it is the OP's responsibility to straighten it. Readers should not have to think extra.

Comment: yes it was a simple typo, thanks for the edit mu is too short

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ruby way to set an empty array as the default value for a Hash would be to use the [`default_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc) version that is in your question:

```
hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [ ] }
```

For example:

```
> hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [ ] }
> hash[:pancakes] << 6
> hash
 => {:pancakes=>[6]}
```

Using standard Ruby features when writing Ruby seems pretty Rubyish to me.

Comment: using [ ] in place of Array.new is even nicer - thanks

Comment: Yeah, about the only time you see `Array.new` is when you need to supply arguments to the constructor (same for `Hash.new`).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen people doing this more often:

```
(h[key] ||= []) << value
```

As that's the explicit way, and rubists like explicitness.

Your version is also common though.

By the way, you can set the defaults on existing hash:

```
h.default_proc = ->(h, k){ h[k] = [] }
```

or

```
h.default = 0
```

And I find that being a bit cleaner, but not as widely used.

Comment: Huh, thats misleading. I'll update the answer than.

Comment: nPn, one consequence of using Bartosz' first approach is that `puts "hello" if h[7]` gives the intended result (so long as `h` does not contain `nil` values), whereas `h[7]` will always be true if the hash is created with a default value, and `h => [7]` (after `h => {}`) if created with `Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}`.  Perhaps the lesson is to always use [`Hash#key?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F) (aka `has_key?`) to check for the presence of a key.

Answer (score -3):

you can set [default](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) value

```
numbers = Hash.new(0)
```